# Trying to install survey Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am following these guides:-

http://www.runtime-revolution.com/runtime/blog/introducing-survey

When I try:-

```
gem "survey", "~> 0.1"
```

as it suggests I get:-

```
ERROR: While executing gem ... <RuntimeError>
    Unknown command survey,
```

When I try:-

```
gem install survey
```

It says that everything has installed fine but when I try:-

```
Rails generate survey plain namespace:contests
```

or

```
rails generate survey:install
```

I get :-

```
Could not find generator
```

Also, looking in my Gemfile survey is not in there?

Comment: https://github.com/runtimerevolution/survey/blob/master/README.md
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/runtimerevolution/survey/frames

Answer (score 0):

```
gem "survey", "~> 0.1"
```

Is not a command. This is the line **you need to manually add** to your [Rails `Gemfile`](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html) to list the gem as dependency in your Rails application, as also explained in the README you linked.

After you add it, run

```
$ bundle
```

and the gem will be installed in your Rails application.

As a side note, you may also benefit from reading some introductory book about using Ruby and Rails.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any recommendations?